# G++ compilation errors with simple programs

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

I tried some C++ programming after trying to learn some C, to see some differences between languages first hand. When trying to compile the program, I get a lot of errors **in libraries** 
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ext/string_conversions.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6493,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from new.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/stdio.h:46:25: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct __sFILE FILE’
   46 |  typedef struct __sFILE FILE;
      |                         ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/cwchar:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from new.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/FILE.h:7:25: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE’
    7 | typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE;
      |                         ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/ext/string_conversions.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6493,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from new.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:99:11: error: ‘::fpos_t’ has not been declared
   99 |   using ::fpos_t;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:101:11: error: ‘::clearerr’ has not been declared
  101 |   using ::clearerr;
      |           ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:102:11: error: ‘::fclose’ has not been declared
  102 |   using ::fclose;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:103:11: error: ‘::feof’ has not been declared
  103 |   using ::feof;
      |           ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:104:11: error: ‘::ferror’ has not been declared
  104 |   using ::ferror;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:105:11: error: ‘::fflush’ has not been declared
  105 |   using ::fflush;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:107:11: error: ‘::fgetpos’ has not been declared
  107 |   using ::fgetpos;
      |           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:109:11: error: ‘::fopen’ has not been declared
  109 |   using ::fopen;
      |           ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:110:11: error: ‘::fprintf’ has not been declared
  110 |   using ::fprintf;
      |           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:114:11: error: ‘::freopen’ has not been declared
  114 |   using ::freopen;
      |           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:115:11: error: ‘::fscanf’ has not been declared
  115 |   using ::fscanf;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:116:11: error: ‘::fseek’ has not been declared
  116 |   using ::fseek;
      |           ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:117:11: error: ‘::fsetpos’ has not been declared
  117 |   using ::fsetpos;
      |           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:118:11: error: ‘::ftell’ has not been declared
  118 |   using ::ftell;
      |           ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:126:11: error: ‘::perror’ has not been declared
  126 |   using ::perror;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:131:11: error: ‘::remove’ has not been declared
  131 |   using ::remove;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:132:11: error: ‘::rename’ has not been declared
  132 |   using ::rename;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:133:11: error: ‘::rewind’ has not been declared
  133 |   using ::rewind;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:135:11: error: ‘::setbuf’ has not been declared
  135 |   using ::setbuf;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:136:11: error: ‘::setvbuf’ has not been declared
  136 |   using ::setvbuf;
      |           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:139:11: error: ‘::tmpfile’ has not been declared
  139 |   using ::tmpfile;
      |           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:141:11: error: ‘::tmpnam’ has not been declared
  141 |   using ::tmpnam;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:176:11: error: ‘::vfscanf’ has not been declared
  176 |   using ::vfscanf;
      |           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:177:11: error: ‘::vscanf’ has not been declared
  177 |   using ::vscanf;
      |           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:179:11: error: ‘::vsscanf’ has not been declared
  179 |   using ::vsscanf;
      |           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:186:22: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::vfscanf’ has not been declared
  186 |   using ::__gnu_cxx::vfscanf;
      |                      ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:187:22: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::vscanf’ has not been declared
  187 |   using ::__gnu_cxx::vscanf;
      |                      ^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/cstdio:189:22: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::vsscanf’ has not been declared
  189 |   using ::__gnu_cxx::vsscanf;
      |                      ^~~~~~~
```

g++ -v command results:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-HskZEa/gcc-9-9.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)
```

Note:

I tried reinstalling g++, because I thought some libraries were corrupted, but it didn't work.
Also, I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, if that's useful

Comment: Can you attach the output of running the command `g++ -v`?

Comment: @rodrigo I edited the post, because it was too long to get it into the comment, you can check it there

Comment: How did you (re-)install GCC/g++?

Comment: @user17732522 through apt, uninstall and then install again
I am quite new to linux, so it might not work as I thought it might

Comment: Since you don't mind reinstalling it, try installing gcc 10.3 which is also available via `sudo apt install g++-10` and use `update-alternatives` to make that the default.

Comment: And what was the complete compiler invocation?

Comment: @TedLyngmo apparently, that version of g++ works perfectly, thank you sir

Comment: @Nuclear303 Wow, cool! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You have a duplicate symbol in a system header `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/stdio.h`. But according to the Ubuntu [manifest](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libgcc-9-dev/filelist), your GCC version does **not** include this file, maybe it has been left stale from a different version?

My adivice is to delete this file, or maybe delete (or move away, just in case) the whole folder (there may be other stale files there) and reinstall the `libgcc-9-dev` package alltogether.

If you want to be sure before deleting the file you can check whether it belongs to any package with the command:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/stdio.h
```